# manipulate a large file python

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have a simple file of 2 GB,17 Millions row
this is an inventory data that looks like the attached 
I am trying to take one column of amount-I am not sure why but at the moment it is a string 
and want to multiple it in the quantity column then I will want to create another column that will take the average for each item and for each month and then create graphs by python or tableau[image] 
I am using python and pandas 
my problem -I cannot convert the amount to int or float
I tried to create a function that loop the data and take each value in the amount field and convert it to a float, because the size of the file this takes a lot of time and I am not sure it will succeed 
I am looking for the simplest way to do this

Comment: Perhaps make a new file containing only the first few rows of the large file to test on.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far so we can check for efficiency too.

Comment: Thank you , I will try the advice here and then I will share the improved code

Answer (score 2):

`df['amount'].to_numeric(errors="coerce")`

should make all values int or float, anything that cannot be converted will become nan

Comment: tried this however I got  
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numeric' this is my code so far inv=pd.read_table(r"C\path\file")  inv['amount']=inv['amount'].to_numeric(errors="coerce")                                      these are the columns: 
amount      565405 non-null object
quantity    565405 non-null object
date        565405 non-null object
material    565405 non-null int64
type        565405 non-null int64
material    565405 non-null object
d/b         565405 non-null object

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, don't give burden to the memory to save that huge data. Below is the example load the data on air by the **yield**

```
def getAmount():
    with open('filename','w+') as fp:
       for data in fp:
           yield int(data['amount']) or float(data['amount'])


for amt in getAmount():
     print(amt)
```